# Sonarqube Generic Coverage - Where are the results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I have a project where I import my unit test results with the Generic Coverage Plugin. My code is written in Javascript.

Now my problem is: I have this widget that contains the percentage of my successful tests. I can see that in every test file. But what I don't know is: Where are the results of each test?  Where can I see which tests are failing?

I saw screenshots on the Internet, but I cannot find them in my sonarqube installation...

Comment: Which SonarQube version ? how does the 'Unit Tests Coverage' widget look currently ? what are you targeting ?

Comment: Version 5.4. [Widget on Dashboard](http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=9793dc-1461143876.png) If i click on tests or the percentage of successful tests i get only [this](http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=9fbd39-1461144189.png). I cannot find a list of the successful or failed tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bit hidden. Clicking on the "Failures" link should display only test files which have failures: choose one test file. Then, next to the number of issues of the test file, there's a button for "More actions" (this same button is at the top right in [this example](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/component/index?id=org.sonarsource.javascript%3Ajavascript-checks-testkit%3Asrc%2Ftest%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fsonar%2Fjavascript%2Fchecks%2Fverifier%2FJavaScriptCheckVerifierTest.java) running on 5.5) . Click on it and then on "Show Details" or "Show Measures": you should have a list of all tests with their status.